# RDLC (Microsoft Report Designer) not available or has been removed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

I want to install RDLC on Visual Studio 2017, but when I try to download it from this link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

it gives me an error, if this addition has been deleted I hope you give me an alternative to RDLC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following steps to install RDLC by using another way.

First,VS Tools->Extensions and Updates->search rdlc report online in the textbox->choose

Microsoft RDLC report Desginer and Microsoft Reporting Services Projects-> Click install.

[image]

Here I have installed them.

Second, you need to restart the vs2017.(remember close all the vs opened windows)

Successfully installed.

[image]

Finally, after install it successfully, you can see that Report and Report Wizard is now

available in the Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

Comment: In fact, I have installed it successfully. By the way, after you close your vs2017, you will see a window about VSIX installer. Please wait it patiently after you see the above window until you see the above Modification completed. If it still exists problem, I suggest that you can try in the another computer or reinstall your vs2017. I have tested it, it works for me.

Comment: J Jun Thanks a lot, I downloaded it from another computer that was successfully downloaded, it looks like the problem was on the other computer or the network.